# How to create bitmap from JNI?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

Am working in H264 video rendering in Android application using SurfaceView. It has one feature to take snapshot.Whenever I take a snapshot, I create the bitmap from JNI.That shows only transparent/black image.

Comment: Please provide more information. No-one can answer your question based on vague information. How are you returning the bitmap? Is it a bitmap object or do you pass the data in a ByteArray? Are you saving it to a file or passing it back to the Java layer and trying to display it? Show some of your code.

Comment: can u please refer this http://grokbase.com/t/gg/android-ndk/139wppy3hc/creating-bitmap-from-framebuffer-byte-array-through-jni-bitmapfactory